# If a is real , then what is the solution set of the inequality $ | x | \leq { a\over x } $?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is there a shorter way than solving it in different cases : ie.

$ x\neq 0 $

Case 1 : a > 0

Subcase 1 : x > 0

Subcase 2 : $ x < 0 $

Case 2 : a < 0

Subcase 1 : x > 0

Subcase 2 : $ x < 0 $

... I can solve it , but I was wondering if theirs a shorter , more efficient approach .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...You can solve this easily if you sketch a graph of $y=|x|$ amd $y=\frac ax$ on the same diagram, considering separately the cases when $a>0$ and $a<0$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $x$ must be non-zero. Then there are two cases: $x>0$ makes $|x|=x$, consequently
$$x\le\frac ax \quad \text{for }x>0$$
and $x<0$, which makes $|x|=-x$ so
$$-x \le\frac ax \quad \text{for }x<0$$

In the first case multiplying by $x$ retains the inequality direction, in the second it gets reversed:
$$\begin{cases}
 x^2 \le a & \text{for }x>0 \\
-x^2 \ge a & \text{for }x<0
\end{cases}$$

that is:
$$\begin{cases}
 x^2 \le a & \text{for }x>0 \\
 x^2 \le -a & \text{for }x<0
\end{cases}$$